# How can I convert the seconds that have passed since last opening the file to hours, minutes and seconds?

Tags: c, time

I want it to look like "It's been 00 hours 00 minutes and 43 seconds since you last opened the file.".
How can I do it so the numbers remain integers, not floats?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int result,h,m,currentTime,previousTime;
    FILE *fp;

    currentTime=time(NULL);
    result=currentTime-previousTime;
    h=(result/3600);
    m=(result/60);


    fp=fopen("aeg.txt","r");

    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("No such file exists\n");
    }else{
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&previousTime);
        printf("It's been %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds since you last opened the file",h,m,result);
        fclose(fp);
    }

        fp=fopen("aeg.txt","w");
        fprintf(fp,"%d",currentTime);
        fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `previousTime` variable is **uninitialized** which makes the `result` wrong.

Changing the order of statements in your program will be enough to fix this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int result,h,m,currentTime,previousTime;
    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("aeg.txt","r");

    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("No such file exists\n");
    }else{
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&previousTime);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    currentTime=time(NULL);
    result=currentTime-previousTime;
    h=(result/3600);
    m=(result/60);

    printf("It's been %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds since you last opened the file",h,m,result);
    fp=fopen("aeg.txt","w");
    fprintf(fp,"%d",currentTime);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

2. Your question about float values is unclear because there are no `float` variables in your program, only `int`.